# What is good way to name parameters in C++ constructors?

Tags: c++

I've learning C++ but I come here from Python. Suppose I want to create a class named `Dog` with parameters such as `name`, `height`, `breed` and `color`. In Python,I would have described name of parameters in constructors with meaningful names, because that is what would appear in good IDE as a hint (or suggestion) while creating an object (I assume same would happen for C++ in IDEs as well). For e.g.,

```
#In python
class Dog:
    def __init__(name, height, breed, color):
        this.name = name
        #....
```

But since C++ doesn't requires (or makes use of) `this` keyword, a book I've been reading (by Goodrich) does something like this

```
class Dog {
    public:
    Dog(string n, double h, string breed_name, string col) :
        name(n), height(h), breed(breed_name), color(col) {}

    private:
    string name;
    double height;
    string breed;
    string color;
};
```

I don't like using `n`, `h` or `breed_name` as parameters as they're not very descriptive, is there some other good way which experienced C++ programmers use to name parameters?

Comment: You can give the parameters the same name as the fields (just like your python example).

Comment: And compiler would auto-understand that `name=name` means it has to assign field `name` to parameter `name` ?

Comment: let me answer fully

Comment: See examples below, but `name=name` is not correct as it just assigns a variable to itself.

Comment: @Deep: It's my understanding that in Python, the proper naming convention for private members is to start their names with an underscore. You shouldn't do that in C++ because there are rules about names beginning with underscores, but the point is that having the parameter name be different from the member is hardly uncommon to Python. For example, an increasingly common C++ idiom is a trailing underscore.

Comment: Questions about coding style are more appropriate for [codereview.se]. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes it is a convention for private member, but not for other members. But single underscore at beginning in Python tells is for other programmers and readers not for interpreter. It just tells them "This is a private member and you shouldn't use it directly", however interpreter doesn't treats it differently; because "We all are responsible users" in Python.

Comment: @Barmar I read that, I was not aware about Code Review, I think it'd be better suited there, can I migrate this question now? How do I do that?

Comment: Click on "flag" and ask the moderators to move it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give the parameters the same name as the fields (just like your python example). This

```
Dog(string name, double height, string breed, string color) :
    name(name), height(height), breed(breed), color(color)
{
}
```

is perfectly correct code.

So is

```
Dog(string name, double height, string breed, string color)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->height = height;
    this->breed = breed;
    this->color = color;
}
```

although using an initializer list should be preferred over using assignment.